# How to write a decorator over a complex class (PersistBackendConn)

Tags: haskell

I need to modify backend logic in Groundhog library
to control table names. The logic is located behind:

```
class (DbDescriptor conn, ConnectionManager conn) 
   => PersistBackendConn conn where
  insert :: ( PersistEntity v 
            , PersistBackend m
            , Conn m ~ conn
            ) 
         => v 
         -> m (AutoKey v)
  ...
```

There is Sqlite type instantiating PersistBackendConn type for SqliteDB.

```
instance PersistBackendConn Sqlite where
  insert v = runDb' $ insert' v
```

To decorate Sqlite I define my type and
I have to reinstantiate PersistBackendConn forwarding to original Sqlite instance.

```
data MySqlite = MySqlite Sqlite

instance PersistBackendConn MySqlite where
  insert v = ??
```

The problem is the signature of insert function doesn't mention conn/Sqlite in a straight forward way.

I don't want to copy/paste cody to reimpelement all logic and the goal is to delegate as much as possible. Most of functions must just forward call to origin function.

I guess m is ReaderT MySqlite IO so following should work, but how to convince type checker?

```
insert v = do
   MySqlite s <- ask
   lift $ flip runReaderT s (insert v)
```

Comment: Hmm, well you will need also some `m` such that `Conn m ~ MySqlite`.